# Find graph function from its graph

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods, graphing-functions, interpolation

> I have a data and plot the function. My task is to approximate the data by some function (as simple as possible). Do you have any idea of which function will fit the best with this plot.[image]

Comment: Try something like $$f(x) = \frac{x^\alpha}{1 + (x/x_0)^\beta}$$

Comment: Hi, many thanks, for which value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Well it depends on the dataset, those are the values you'll need to fit